# No resistance measured between two electrical parts, ECU fault?

Tags: electrical, electronic-control-module

I'm troubleshooting a car with a faulty Camshaft Sensor error.

I used the factory test plan to test the wiring between the sensor & ECU.

Here is the wiring:

ECU Pin87 -> Wireloom Pin 87 -> Camshaft Wire Pin 2 -> Camshaft sensor

According to factory diagnostic test, Pin2 Camshaft wire is suppose to have an expected resistance of >5 ohms between the pin and car body ground. However, when I measured it, there is no resistance measured as if the two parts are not connected.

I then disconnected the wire from the  ECU and tested the wire on both end (pin87 and pin2), there is continuity in the wiring so the wire from the Camshaft to ECU is ok.

Is this an indication some fault upstream the ECU? The problem is that we've sent the ECU to Bosch for repair and they sent back the unit saying there is no fault.

Any idea on how to continue the diagnosis?

Comment: What is pin 2 supposed to carry? Ground? Is it a low ref?

Comment: Do you really mean NO resistance (0 Ohms), which means a short circuit, or infinite resistance, which means an open circuit (break or other disconnection)?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It would also be helpful if you could provide the year/make/model/engine for the vehicle you're testing. This will help us be on an even ground with you in helping with your diagnostic.